# Having trouble using user input between functions

Tags: python, function, scope

I'm trying to learn Python and I'm really struggling with getting my code into self-contained functions. Here is an example:

```
def get_inputs():
    sales_amount = float(input("Enter total sales amount: "))

def calculate_discount(sales_amount):
    discount_amount = sales_amount * 2 
    return discount_amount

def output():
    print ( discount_amount )

def main():
    get_inputs()
    calculate_discount(sales_amount)
    output()

main()
```

Running this returns

```
File "/Users/Desktop/assA3.py", line 17, in <module>
main()

File "/Users/Desktop/assA3.py", line 14, in main
calculate_discount(sales_amount)

NameError: name 'sales_amount' is not defined
```

I thought the variable `sales_amount` was defined by the user input before it is referenced later. I can't figure out what I'm missing.

I apologise for how basic this problem is but I'm clearly misunderstanding something fundamental and I'm just really struggling. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to use function scope variables in other functions. Nothing outside of function `get_inputs` can see variable `sales_amount`, its a variable local to that function. You will encounter the same issue with `discount_amount`, which is scoped to `calculate_discount`.

Instead return the values and pass them to other functions.

```
def get_inputs():
    return float(input("Enter total sales amount: "))

def calculate_discount(sales_amount):
    discount_amount = sales_amount * 2 
    return discount_amount

def output(discount_amount):
    print ( discount_amount )

def main():
    inputs = get_inputs()
    discounts = calculate_discount(inputs)
    output(discounts)

main()
```

The dirty option is to make them globals

```
def get_inputs():
    global sales_amount
    sales_amount = float(input("Enter total sales amount: "))

def calculate_discount(sales_amount):
    global discount_amount
    discount_amount = sales_amount * 2 
    return discount_amount

def output():
    print ( discount_amount )

def main():
    get_inputs()
    calculate_discount(sales_amount)
    output()

main()
```

Globals are slower, make your code more difficult to maintain and are bad for a whole raft of reasons.

Comment: Thankyou Paul and others below. Speedy and comprehensive, I really appreciate it.

Comment: Done and thanks again. Just a quick follow-up. Taking the first example of the get_inputs function, am I able to return two separate values? eg:  return input1, input2

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is to pass `sales_amount` out of `gets_input()`:

```
def get_inputs():
    sales_amount = float(input("Enter total sales amount: "))
    return sales_amount
```

and to use it in `main()`:

```
def main():
    sales_amount = get_inputs()
    calculate_discount(sales_amount)
    output()
```

If you want to make it "self-contained" then you want to use classes:

```
class Sales(object):
    def get_inputs(self):
        self.sales_amount = float(input("Enter total sales amount: "))

    def calculate_discount(self):
        self.discount_amount = self.sales_amount * 2 

    def output(self):
        print ( self.discount_amount )


def main():
    my_sale = Sales()
    my_sale.get_inputs()
    my_sale.calculate_discount()
    my_sale.output()

main()
```

Answer (score 0):

in each of get_inputs, calculate_discounts and main, sales_amount is a local variable.  It might make more sense to you if each subroutine used a different variable name where presently all three use sales_amount.

I suggest that get_inputs return a result, and that main store the result of get_inputs into a variable that is then passed to calculate_discounts.

Answer (score 0):

This is because variables defined in functions are local in Python.

See [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291978/short-description-of-python-scoping-rules/292502#292502) to help you understand from where you can access variables.

In your case, you should just pass sales_amount as a parameter to your function, as others have pointed out :)